# What is this little section of concrete called?

Tags: terminology

[image]

This concrete/triangle object is the object in question. (Image from Google Maps).

Comment: Wow, your traffic engineer graduated from the Joan Miro school of engineering? We have an [Engineering.SE] SE that is probably a better place for this question. It has a "traffic intersections" tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These types of things which are raised in height from the road surface are usually called "[traffic islands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traffic_island)". They're not meant to be driven on, and are often (not always for pedestrians to stand on so as to be out of the way of cars' paths.

I checked if there's a more particular term for this by searching for "pedestrian island" (what I'd instinctively call it), and I got the result of this Wikipedia [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refuge_island) whose title is "refuge island". In the first sentence of the article it mentioned these are also known as "pedestrian refuges" and "pedestrian island".

> A refuge island, also known as a pedestrian refuge, pedestrian island
>   and colloquially as a "pork chop" island, is a small section of
>   pavement or sidewalk, completely surrounded by asphalt or other road
>   materials, where pedestrians can stop before finishing crossing a
>   road.
>  [Refuge island / pedestrian island](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refuge_island)

It seems to be a general term for where pedestrians can with relative safety stand without potentially being hit by cars, whether this is during completing a crossing, or maybe something else.

Interestingly, traffic islands and what are called [median strips](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_strip) in some places, are related. If you're crossing a road you may make the road-crossing trip in two phases, from one side of the road to the median strip / traffic island, from which you can observe whether it's safe to complete the second part of the crossing.

Note some of these terms may differ from region to region.

Also note that in your particular photo pedestrians generally don't stand on the raised portion (the island), but rather walk along the marked paths and stand between the islands. I imagine this gives some safety as you have raised islands surrounding you.